# TCPDF - why margin-left not working?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Why in TCPDF library margin left is not working ? I got the example from TCPDF site:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_002.phps

and modify and add:

```
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(0);
```

but this not working on left margin. TOP and RIGHT are working fine, but not left. Why?
How can I set 0 on LeftMargin?

I have:

```
// File name   : tcpdf.php
// Version     : 6.0.020
// Begin       : 2002-08-03
// Last Update : 2013-06-04
```

Comment: What is the margin set to?

Answer (score 0):

try setting your cell padding to zero.

```
$pdf->setCellPaddings(0,0,0,0);
```